# Jquery ajax и cookie

Tags: ajax, php, cookie

Добрый день!
Проблема заключается в следующем: передаю через ajax функцию числовое значение:

```
function ajax_svernut_menu(id) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_script/left_menu.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: 'id=' + id
});
```

}

В left_menu.php устанавливаю значение куки в id, принятом в запроса, но кука постоянно установлена в значение "0". В чем может быть причина, учитывая то, что без ajax (просто в php файле) кука устанавливается правильно.

```
        if((int)$_COOKIE['left_menu_'.$id] > 0) setcookie('left_menu_'.$id, 0, time()+60*60*24*30, "/") ;
    else setcookie('left_menu_'.$id, 1, time()+60*60*24*30, "/") ;
```

Comment: Покажите как вы получаете переменную **$id**

Вы уверены, что ниже не перезаписываете эти куки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы передаете числовое значение, при этом данные отправляются в строке. Я правильно понял?
Если, да, то разве не так лучше будет:

```
function ajax_svernut_menu(id) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_script/left_menu.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: id
});
```

Уберите кавычки в параметре "data".

Answer (score 0):

```
if((int ) $_POST[id] > 0) { setcookie( 'left_menu_' . $id, $_POST['id'] , time ()+ 60* 60* 24* 30, "/" ) ;  }
```

Comment: $id = abs((int)$_POST['id']) ;

И это условие не верное "if((int ) $POST[id] > 0)" - мне нужно проверять какое значение в куке.

Comment: в куке может быть 0 или 1

Comment: if((int)$_COOKIE['left_menu_'.$id] > 0) setcookie('left_menu_'.$id, 1, time()+60*60*24*30, "/") ; else setcookie('left_menu_'.$id, 0, time()+60*60*24*30, "/") ;

Comment: если в $_POST['id'] будет лежать "12HELLOWORD" то она уйдет в куки (это по ответу)